# How to use numpy vectorization to find different data columns in the same column of two huge dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, vectorization

I have two dataframes, `df1` and `df2`, both have the same column `date`.
The `date` column of `df1` has about tens of millions of rows, and the `date` column of `df1` is incomplete and may be duplicated. `df2` is about a few thousand rows. The `date` column of `df2` is complete and not repeated. How to use `numpy` `vectorization` to find out the `date1` data that does not exist in `df1` but exists in `df2` and generate an `numpy` `ndarray`?
I tried `np.where` and `groupby.size`, but I couldn't find the correct way to use them.

Comment: `df2[~df2['date'].isin(df1['date'])]`.

Comment: or if you just want the dates, you can  do with Python: `set(df2['date']).differrence(set(df1['date']))`.

Comment: @QuangHoang Please don't post answers as comments.

Comment: @orlp, Quang has an edge on you in reputation :)  I know there are differences in opinion on this, but my philosophy is to comment if it's a quick, untested idea.  My answers are much longer with explanation and test.  And yes, sometimes the OP asks me to make it an answer so he can check if off.  Better that then being scolded for going the otherway :)

Comment: `set(df2['date']).differrence(set(df1['date']))` takes `AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'differrence'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use this on top of recommended solutions in comments:

```
df2[~np.in1d(df2['date'],df1['date'])]['date'].to_numpy()
```

Comment: This method took me more than ten minutes to execute, but the result was correct.
Before I execute this statement, I execute `df1 = df1.drop_duplicates(['date'])`, and the speed is very fast.
In the two answers of Quang Hoang, `df2[~df2['date'].isin(df1['date'])]` can be executed normally, but `set(df2['date']).differrence(set(df1[ 'date']))` brings an error, because Quang Hoang uses comments,  Ehsan and Chuncheng's answers are the same, Ehsan answers first, so I accepted @Ehsan's answer

Answer (score 1):

I generate a demo dataset as you described, if my understanding is correct.
My finding is the function is simple, however, the time costing is not.

- If you can wait, the recommended solution is a choice,
  since it will cost about 0.4 / 4 seconds to scan the 10,000 / 100,000 sized df1,
  and it grows linearly,
  I believe it will reach to the intolerable long for your application;
- If you have large enough memory, you can use my "Set solution", it will provide the same(correct) result and cost only 0.1885 seconds on 3,000,000 sized df1.

```
--------------- Experiment [10000] starts ------------------------------
Recommended solution [10000] costs 0.49669885635375977 seconds
Set solution [10000] costs 0.001967191696166992 seconds
[ True]
--------------- Experiment [100000] starts ------------------------------
Recommended solution [100000] costs 4.4930009841918945 seconds
Set solution [100000] costs 0.006981611251831055 seconds
[ True]
--------------- Experiment [1000000] starts ------------------------------
Set solution [1000000] costs 0.06779003143310547 seconds
--------------- Experiment [3000000] starts ------------------------------
Set solution [3000000] costs 0.18847417831420898 seconds
```

Following is my code

```py
# %%
import time
import random
import datetime
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# %%
n = int(3e3)
today = datetime.date.today()
delta = datetime.timedelta(days=1)

for k in [int(1e4), int(1e5), int(1e6), int(3e6)]:
    print(
        f'--------------- Experiment [{k}] starts ------------------------------')
    days = ['{}'.format(today + i * delta) for i in range(n)]

    # Generate df2
    df2 = pd.DataFrame()
    df2['date'] = days
    df2

    # Generate df1
    df1 = pd.DataFrame()
    df1['date'] = random.choices(days[:-10], k=k)
    df1

    # Recommended solution.
    # It won't run at n of 1e6, since it will cost too much time.
    if k < 1e6:
        t0 = time.time()
        o1 = df2[~np.in1d(df2['date'], df1['date'])]['date']
        print(f'Recommended solution [{k}] costs', time.time() - t0, 'seconds')
        o1

    # Set solution
    t0 = time.time()
    set1 = set(df1['date'])
    o2 = df2['date'][df2['date'].map(lambda x: x not in set1)]
    print(f'Set solution [{k}] costs', time.time() - t0, 'seconds')
    o2

    # Compare the results of the two solutions
    if k < 1e6:
        print((o1 == o2).unique())

# %%
```

Comment: It seems to be the same with the answer with @Quang Hoang, I did not see it, when I posted the commit. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

I found another way, use `np.setdiff1d`, the code is as follows:

```
from time import time
start = time()
n2 = np.setdiff1d(df2.date.values, df1.date.drop_duplicates().to_numpy())
print('len df1:%d  df2:%d' % (len(df1), len(df2)))
stop = time()
print(stop - start)
```

Result is:

```
len df1: 11351055  df2:7406  
1.6254549026489258
```